# When scrolling and fixing my navbar on top, it has a wonky movement effect

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, navbar, responsive

I am working with a template and the navbar has a strange movement when it fixes on top. I am using bootstrap.
Here you can see a little video with the situation: http://i.imgur.com/trrmJj7.gifv

I tried changing the color of the menu to black so it fixes also to black but it still has the same effect. Tried also in various browsers. Cant this be fixed or is it a bug?

Here is my HTML:

```
<div id="menu">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
                <div class="container">
                    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" 
                            data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#menu-content">
                            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        </button>
                          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                            <img src="img/other/03_Logo.png"> <span>BRAND</span>
                          </a>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="menu-content">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#service">Services</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#experience">Profile</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#testimonial">Testimonials</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
                </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
            </nav>
        </div>
```

And CSS:

```
#menu {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0; }
  #menu nav {
    border: medium none;
    background: black;
    margin-bottom: 0px; }
  #menu nav.navbar {
    padding: 10px 0px;
    border-radius: 0; }
    #menu nav.navbar.navbar-fixed-top {
      padding: 5px 0px; }
 #menu nav.navbar-fixed-top {
    background: black; }
  #menu .navbar-brand {
    padding: 15px 0px 0px 15px; }
    #menu .navbar-brand img {
      width: 45px;
      float: left;
      margin-top: -10px; }
    #menu .navbar-brand span {
      float: left;
      display: block; }
```

Comment: This navbar is present at bottom

Answer (score 1):

Remove from your css, property `bottom: 0` given to id `#menu`. Then it should work fine.

Comment: No because the menu starts at the bottom, and when you scroll then it fixes at the top. But I think I will have to leave it like that, I can't seem to solve it @Manish

Comment: @Mariana: after u removed bottom: 0 , it will be fixed at top

Comment: Yes but that is not my question, now i know its a bootsrap issue